# How to speed up an operation between two arrays of different sizes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, multidimensional-array, numpy-ndarray

I have two arrays which are lists of points in 3D space. These arrays have different lengths.

```
np.shape(arr1) == (34709, 3)
np.shape(arr2) == (4835053, 3)
```

I have a function which can compute the Pythagorean distance between a single point in one array and all points in another, given periodic boundary conditions:

```
def pythag_periodic(array, point, dimensions):
    delta = np.abs(array - point)
    delta = np.where(delta > 0.5 * dimensions, delta - dimensions, delta)
    return np.sqrt((delta ** 2).sum(axis=-1))
```

I am trying to apply this operation to all points in both arrays. I have a loop which calls this function recursively, but it is agonisingly slow.

```
for i in arr1:
    pp.append(pythag_periodic(arr2, i, dimensions))
```

Any suggestions as to how I might speed this up would be much appreciated.

Comment: I would take a look at the multiprocessing library- in particular Pool. https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html

Comment: You are looking at a final matrix of size `34709 x 4835053`. Are you sure you have the memory for it?

Comment: Few things to checkout, map reduce, PyCUDA , running the computationally intensive portion with C/C++ bindings.

Comment: You can also change the line computing the eucledian distance to use np.linalg.norm()

Comment: You can chunk this data up into parts and run on separate processes and merge results into one.

Comment: For best performance with Numba write out the whole function (also the outer part) in simple loops. For the result you can also use a simple pre-array allocated array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use numba : https://numba.pydata.org/ (disclosed: I am not the author). It is a library that translates Python functions to optimized machine code at runtime. Thus, Numba-compiled numerical algorithms in Python can approach the speeds of C or FORTRAN.

To apply to your code is really simple. In a nutshell, import the library and then use the decorator. Besides, you have more options that can be relevant for you like Parallelize Your Algorithms (have a look to their website).
For instance:

```
from numba import jit


@jit(nopython=True)
def pythag_periodic(array, point, dimensions):
    delta = np.abs(array - point)
    delta = np.where(delta > 0.5 * dimensions, delta - dimensions, delta)
    return np.sqrt((delta ** 2).sum(axis=-1))
```

Comment: Note that Numba will not provide a big improvement by only jitting this function. This should be much faster is the loop iterating on `arr1` is jitted too. Note also that Numba can even parallelize this encompassing loop (if requested).

Answer (score 1):

Another cool option would be to exploit Numpy's [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html#broadcasting) (via the `None` keyword when indexing the arrays) and the super neat [`einsum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html#numpy-einsum) function to avoid the loop and perform the sum and square operations simultaneously, respectively.

Note however that this approach is slighty slower for small matrices, but once you get to sizes greater than 4000 elements or so it is much faster. Also, beware of running out of RAM as vectorization has this downside (although you are already storing the `NxM` array in your code anyways).

```
import numpy as np

def pythag_periodic_vectorized(a1, a2):
    delta = np.abs(a1[:,None,:] - a2[None,...])
    delta = np.where(delta > 0.5 * a1.shape[1], delta - a1.shape[1], delta)

return np.sqrt(np.einsum("ijk,ijk->ij", delta, delta))
```